# check if numbers exist in a structure field

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, indexing, structure

I have a set of values in a vector that I would like to loop over to check whether they exist in a structure field--is there any easy way to do this without causing an index error. I want to check whether all of the values in j,

```
where j=[1:79 356:366], exist in my structure files(1,1).day(j).median.
```

I was trying to loop over the elements of j and set restrictions via if then statements. The cases I would like to test but am not sure how to test are:

-whether the values exist in the structure field. If they exist I would like to calculate a value

-whether they are empty (no data) I would like to skip them and continue looping through the rest of the values of j

-whether they exist in the structure field at all--skip and continue looping through the rest of the values of j

-If 80% of the numbers exist I would like to calculate something as well.

I've tried a slew of things but keep getting the indexing error. Can anyone point me to how I would set up this logic?

Comment: Post your most successful attempt.

Comment: Do you really use `j` for defining the values (`j=[1:79 356:366]`) _and_ for indexing (`files(1,1).day(j).median`) at the same time?

Comment: @Luis:Well I was trying to, but perhaps I should use another index that uses the days that I actually have? That's probably why I'm getting the index error...

Comment: @Dan, I will get something up soon